# How can I treat specific warnings as errors in C++ to be cross-platform?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, preprocessor, pragma

I need to treat some specific warnings as errors to ensure the program runs as it is supposed to. For instance, functions with the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute should always return, otherwise the compiler prints an error. In Visual Studio (MSVC), it is easy to do that with:

```
#pragma warning (error: warning_id)
```

This works perfectly. But I run this code on a cluster, where I use either GCC, Clang or the Intel compiler, so I would like to implement this to be portable. Something like:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    #pragma warning (error: 4834)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    // what here?
#elif defined(__clang__)
    // what to put here?
#else
    // Another compiler...
#endif
```

I suppose Intel is similar to MSVC; in Clang, there is an option to treat an error as warning `-Wno-error=some_error`, which would help me the other way around, but there may be too many warnings, which I would rather not treat as errors.

What should I do?

Comment: You need to invert checks for `__GNUC__` and `__clang__`, because Clang, for compatibility, actually defines `__GNUC__`!

Comment: @prapin thanks for the advice, I did not know that!

Comment: @prapin And clang-cl defines both `MSC_VER` and `__clang__`. But, fortunately, it also supports both forms of the `#pragma`. :)

Comment: I actually do not use clang-cl (maybe in the future), but it might help in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For GCC and clang, the `#pragma` to elevate a specific warning to an error is very similar.

For GCC:

```c
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wunused-result"
```

For clang:

```c
#pragma clang diagnostic error "-Wunused-result"
```

The Intel C/C++ compiler does, as you presume, support the MSVC-style `#pragma` (and it also defines the `_MSC_VER` macro, so you can use the same `#if defined...` block).

For "other" compilers, it's clearly very difficult to say – you would need to check the manual for each compiler you are likely to use. As far as I know, there is no *standard* (cross-platform) way to do this. Also note that, just because a compiler pre-defines the `_MSC_VER` macro, does not *guarantee* that it will also support all MSVC-style `#pragma` syntax.

Comment: There is also `#pragma clang diagnostic push` and `#pragma clang diagnostic pop` to treat diagnostic settings as a stack, which can be useful if you're, say, `#include`ing a file that you know produces warnings and you want to shut them up (but only for that file).

Comment: @AdriaandeGroot Yes - those can be helpful, and GCC also has them.

Comment: @AdriaandeGroot I actually use this in a cross-platform fashion to silence warnings from armadillo library, here is the code if you're interested: https://pastebin.com/hS2LhmUN